# Set default value in EF designer datetime

Tags: entity-framework-4

Trying to set the default value of a datetime field to take current time. In SQL's field designer i'd use **getdate()**. What should i use in Entity Framework's designer?

thx

Comment: any luck with my below answer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set '**StoredGeneratedPattern**' to `Computed` against the field in the EDMX.

You still need the default value in SQL Server though, the above setting will ensure EF honour's that.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. Turns out it's not allowing to set value, it's always default value taken. I had to finally do some nasty solution with partial class ...

Answer (score 3):

Building upon [RPM1984's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4688135/1718128):

1. Select the field that has the default value,*Created_On* in my example, within your EDMX file
2. Go to the **Properties** panel
3. Select the **StoreGeneratedPattern** attribute
4. Then change the value to **Computed**

[image: EDMX to Properties panel]

Answer (score 0):

kidos for this answer although it didn't worked for me after setting **StoreGeneratedPattern** attribute value to **Computed** but setting **StoreGeneratedPattern** attribute value to **Identity** worked for me , i was setting default "Guid" to UserID of **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type**

Answer (score -1):

Setting default values in Entity Framework 5 and 6 by changing T4 Template File

Made below changes in .tt(template file) 
remove if condition at line 34

```
34 if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || collectionNavigationProperties.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
35 {
```

add

```
59 OnCreated();
60 }
61
62 partial void OnCreated();
63 <#
```

refer this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdlNB.png
red means remove and green means add

This will add constructor in all entity classes with OnCreated method.

Like below

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
      this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
      OnCreated();
    }

 partial void OnCreated();
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then create class file using same namespace that of Entities.

```
public partial class Category
{
   partial void OnCreated()
   {
      Name = "abc"
   }
}
```

refer below answer for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882032/5475124

Comment: It is quite nasty solution, but I didn't find anything better...

Answer (score -4):

Right click edmx, open with, choose xml editor, find "ProviderManifestToken"  change from 2008 to 2005.  Save.