# FormView tries to insert Null from Blank TextBoxes

Tags: entity-framework, formview

I'm using a FormView control with the EntityFramework. I'm trying to add a new record, but every time I leave a text box blank, instead of inserting an empty string, it tries to insert a null.

How do I control this behavior so that it will use an empty string instead of a null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can handle this in the different levels of your application:

1) you can set default value in `ItemCreated` event handler and set default value there.

2) If you have permission to modify dblayer, you can set default value for column in db (or, maybe it is already set) and then set `StoreGenerationPattern` to `Computed` (look at, for example [Entity Model - How to use Database's Default Column Values while inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842088/entity-model-how-to-use-databases-default-column-values-while-inserting/6844875#6844875))